# disable a specefic sidebar when user is log out

Tags: functions, filters, actions

I want to disable a profile sidebar when users are logout

```
if (is_active_sidebar('profile')) :
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
        dynamic_sidebar('profile');
    else :
        dynamic_sidebar('-----');//fake name
    endif;
endif;
```

I put the above code in function.php but does not work.

Comment: It's not going to do anything in functions.php. You need to add the check in the template wherever the sidebar is originally output.